# How to handle IN clause with many elements in Calcite SQL within Apache BEAM

Tags: sql, apache-beam, apache-calcite

I'm using Apache Beam version 2.29 and doing a sql transform. I have an `IN` clause in my sql with with many elements within (50+). When running I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
> CROSS JOIN, JOIN ON FALSE is not supported!

After some troubleshooting I found out that it's because `IN` only supports up to 19 elements (bug or feature?). I split my `IN` in smaller chunks with an `OR` but now I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException: Code of
> method
> "eval0(Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/Schema;Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn$ProcessContext;Lorg/apache/beam/vendor/calcite/v1_20_0/org/apache/calcite/DataContext;)V"
> of class "SC" grows beyond 64 KB

Any idea what to do?

Comment: Could you file a Jira with steps to reproduce ?  https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/

Answer (score 0):

try search IN_SUB_QUERY_THRESHOLD, beyond IN_SUB_QUERY_THRESHOLD, `in` will be translated to `join`